# Trusting a Self Signed Certificate on RHEL7

Tags: linux, redhat, certificate, self-signed-certificate

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to import a self-signed certificate of one of our servers to one of our development boxes.

I've tried adding the .cer file from the server to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source (and have tried /anchor as well)` then running `update-ca-trust extract` but with no success. It feels like I'm missing something when doing it, but after searching through Google and ServerFault, I haven't found anything that works for us.

Comment: What TLS client are you using?

Comment: @JohnMahowald I'm not entirely sure. The certificate was generated, as far as I know, using OpenSSL, and we've been, unfortunately, testing with Lynx as the client as the servers are all placed inside a zone where we have very limited access to anything and don't have a normal desktop browser.